# teradata syntax error expected something like a name or a unicode delimited identifier or an udfcallname keyword between ) and the union keyword

Tags: sql, teradata, union, teradata-sql-assistant

In my SQL query I'm trying to union two tables together however, whenever I run the query I get the following error message: teradata syntax error expected something like a name or a unicode delimited identifier or an udfcallname keyword between ')' and the 'union' keyword. Below is a snippet of the query. What is causing this issue and what edit should I make to resolve this issue?

```
 FROM 
(SELECT RUN_DT, CAST(LOB AS VARCHAR(11)) AS LOB, MBRID, MEDICAID_NBR, CAST(DISEASE_COND AS VARCHAR(50)) AS DISEASE_COND,CAST(DISEASE_COND_NAME AS VARCHAR(100)) AS DISEASE_COND_NAME, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(150)) AS HCC_SUBCAT_DESC, PLAN_DIM_CK,
STATE_CODE, GAP_IND1, GAP_IND2, RISK_MODEL, AID, PRO_GENERIC_PRODUCT_DESC, RATE_CELL_DESC, DIAG, DIAG_DESC,
DOS, NDC, NDC_DESC, MEMBER_MONTHS, RISK_SCORE, GAP_PROBABILITY
FROM MEDICAID_CONDITIONS)
        UNION ALL
(SELECT RUN_DT, LOB, MEMBERID AS MBRID,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(30)) AS MEDICAID_NBR, DISEASE_COND, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(40)) AS DISEASE_COND_NAME,DISEASE_COND_NAME, PLAN_DIM_CK,
STATE_CODE, GAP_IND1, GAP_IND2, CAST(RISK_MODEL AS VARCHAR(20)) AS RISK_MODEL, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) AS AID, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(72)) AS PRO_GENERIC_PRODUCT_DESC, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(72)) AS RATE_CELL_DESC, DIAG, DIAG_DESC,
DOS, NDC, NDC_DESC, MEMBER_MONTHS, RISK_SCORE, GAP_PROBABILITY
FROM MARKETPLACE_CONDITIONS) AS M
```

Comment: `FROM (SELECT ....)` requires an ALIAS on that subquery. `FROM (SELECT ...) as subquery` (or something). Your subquery just before your UNION lacks the required alias. If that doesn't fix it, please post the entire SQL.

Comment: Try putting parens around the entire from clause.  Right now you have Select *stuff* from *query1* UNION *query2*.  This seems a bit ambiguous - what does the UNION bind to?

Comment: At a glance, you have no reason for the derived tables.  You just want `select <columns> from medicaid_conditions union all select <columns> from marketplace_conditions`.